Desktop crashing approx. ~1/day reporting Q-code 15
I have an Ubuntu system that I put together and started using in the past few months. Lately it's been plagued with hard crashes - about once a day it'll restart without warning, and I have to sign in and launch everything again. When that happens the motherboard reports Q-code 15, which is supposedly "memory initialization".
If my desktop is off for several days, it sometimes has graphical issues when resuming. After a work trip recently I brought it up from suspension and one monitor was flickering every few seconds. After about an hour of that, the system crashed per usual.

OS: Ubuntu 24.10 (issues began under 24.04.1)
MOBO: ASUS ROG STRIX X670E-E
Processor: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X
Graphics: AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT
RAM: 2x G.SKILL Trident Z5 Neo (32gb ea)
Disk: 2x Samsung SSD 970 Evo Plus (2tb ea)

Is there a known error causing this? What should my next step be to troubleshoot the issue? A friend suggested re-seating the RAM sticks; they're currently in 2 and 4, and that's the only configuration that successfully boots. They also said I should try updating the BIOS, but fwupd doesn't report a pending update.
Edit: recently updated to 24.10, and have still experienced crashes since. I've gotten in the habit of suspending my desktop anytime I leave it for more than an hour; this is lengthened the time between crashes to once every few days. Based on that it feels like there's a particular uptime limit that's causing the crash, which makes me think this is memory-related, but I'm not sure where to start investigating that.

Definitely worth testing your memory - this link should help. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest

memtest86+ returned 0 errors across 2 passes. I'm not sure what to try next.
